# <noscript> when using react-router v2 with browser history

Tags: react-router

I tried to use the browserHistory to make the clean URLs, but when I access the web page, the page is blank and in my console I got <'noscript'> tag. I am using react-router v2.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM, { render } from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App';
import InputForm from './components/InputForm';
import FilterSummary from './components/FilterSummary';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';


render((
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path='/' component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={InputForm} />
            <Route path='/filter' component={FilterSummary} />
        </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

Server is WebLogic, so I am not sure how to configure it, as the example only shows it in Express JS. Any idea how to solve this?

EDIT:

Adding screenshot of the HTML response

[All JSX is not rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbfKi.png)

Comment: Where do you see `<noscript>`? I believe noscript is what React renders for `null`. Does your `App` render anything?

Comment: I added a link to the screenshot of the HTML response. It should render something, but it did not once I use browserHistory.

Comment: Does [React dev tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en) give you anything helpful? Does `console.log(Router, App)` give you expected output?

Comment: I've the same problem in production environment. If I remove `history={browserHistory}` all works fine. Do you find a solution?

Comment: @NickGnd unfortunately I have not found the solution and keep on using the hashHistory for now. Hopefully someone else can solve this problem.